# Magento bundle special price issue

Tags: magento, bundle

Having an issue here with our online store using Magento CE 1.7.0.2.

I'm working on bundle and I would like to have special on those bundle. Price is set as fixed when creating the bundle and I set the special to whatever I want.

So for example I have a bundle product let say the price is a 100. My special price is 50. So on the product page I should have both the special price and the regular price (with a line through).
Well I only have the special price. It's working fine with non bundle products.

That's my first issue.

Second issue is that I have a block with random products on sale. The thing is I have (again) an issue with bundle. Inside my block I have the regular price showing at 0 (for bundle only) but with a line through.
All I do is a getPrice() on the product, it's working fine with everything but bundle. Should I use something else than getPrice() to get the regular price of a bundle product ?

I went into my database and I have the column price with the correct default price, just like non bundle produts. Only difference is that the price_type is set to 1 for the bundle and default for the others.

I searched around but couldn't find a proper solution, only people with the same kind of issue.
If anyone has any idea or a solution it would be nice of you to share. I'll update this thread if I make any progress and post the solution if I find it.

Thx :-)

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution ?